# Running builds inside each stage parallel in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

I currently have the stages running in parallel, but how about the tests inside of those stages.  Can they also be run in parallel? Can this be done using parallel again?

```
//List for all the tests
def TeamA_Tests = ["AAA","AAA1"]
def TeamB_Tests = ["BBB","BBB1"]
def TeamC_Tests = ["CCC","CCC1"]
def TeamD_Tests = ["DDD","DDD1","DDD3"]

//Pipeline
node('master') {
   parallel("stream 1(A)" : {
    stage('A') { // for display purposes
       for (item in TeamA_Tests) {
            buildJob(item)
            }
        }
   },
   "stream 2(B)" : {
    stage('B') {
        for (item in TeamB_Tests) {
            buildJob(item)
            }
        }
    },
   "stream 3 (C)" : {
    stage('C') {
        for (item in TeamC_Tests) {
            buildJob(item)
            }
        }
    },
   "stream 4 (D)" : {
    stage('D') {
        for (item in TeamD_Tests) {
            buildJob(item)
            }
        }
    }
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

> - Nested parallel blocks can lead to swamping your available executors, as each execution of the first parallel block calls multiple executions of the second parallel block, and so on. In general, think carefully about your parallelism and your available executors when using parallel.
> - The [Parallel Test Executor plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parallel-test-executor-plugin) is awesome and can be immensely helpful both for distributing your test execution and for throttling your parallelism, since you define how many "buckets" your tests get divided into.

Source: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/docs/BEST_PRACTICES.md